# Select a document by id on Mongo or Elasticsearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, database-design, mongodb-query, database

I am using Elasticsearch along with MongoDB.
Mongo is my primary DB and Elasticsearch is used for search feature.
Mongo changes are synched to Elssticsearch using Mongo Oplog.

I have a case where I need to get a document by passing document id(i.e., Mongo '_id'). Which DB is efficient for this query, Mongo DB or Elasticsearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this Id is also your shard key in MongoDb then Mongo would be more efficient as it would know in which shard to look. Elasticsearch will search all of the shards and so be less efficient.

If MongoDb is your single source of truth and you have the Id then use Mongo. If you need full text search then use Elasticsearch.